# Java remove non Latin-basic characters from string

Tags: java, regex, unicode

Let's say I have the following code:

```
String description = "★★★★★  ♫ ♬ This description ✔✔  ▬ █ ✖  is a mess. ♫ ♬ ★★★★★";
```

I'd like to remove the non-Latin characters: `✔`, `▬`, `█`, `✖`, `♫`, `♬` and `★`.

And have it become this: `This description is a mess.`

I know there's probably tons of these wingdings-like characters, so instead of specifying what I'd like to remove, I think it's better to list what I want to keep: [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) and [Latin-1 supplements](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) characters.

I found that I can use the following code to remove everything but the basic latin characters

`String clean_description = description.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "").trim();`

But is there a way to also preserve the Latin-1 supplement characters?

Comment: Since it looks like that range comes right after basic latin, couldn't you just change the regex to this: `"[^\\x00-\\xFF]"`?

Comment: @resueman this sounds like an answer...

Comment: Try `\p{S}` regex, see my post below

Comment: @Saleem comment **and** answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From looking at the character ranges you provided, it appears that "Basic Latin" and "Latin-1 Supplements" are adjacent (`0x00`-`0x7F` and `0x80`-`0xFF`).

So you can use the same regex you provided, just extended out to include the "Latin-1 Supplement" characters. That would look like this:

```
String clean_description = description.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\xFF]", "").trim();
```

As pointed out in the comments by [Quinn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741681/ccf), this does not get rid of the spaces between the removed sections, so the result has excess spaces (which may or may not be what you want). If you want those spaces removed, Quinn's regex (`[^(\\x00-\\xFF)]+(?:$|\\s*)`, in case the comment is deleted) may work for you.

Comment: The result string has more spaces in between words. Is this OP's desired format? Suggest using `[^(\\x00-\\xFF)]+(?:$|\\s*)`, and getting rid of `trim()`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a more descriptive expression use this:

```
description.replaceAll( "[^\\p{InBasic_Latin}\\p{InLatin-1Supplement}]", "" );
```

or the intersection of the negations `[\P{InBasic_Latin}&&\P{InLatin-1Supplement}]` (not that it's more readable ;) )

Comment: I've tested all the answers and it seems like this is the only one that actually preserves the `$` character (which is part of the Latin-1 supplement chars).

Comment: @RoboticR using `[^\x00-\xFF]` would do the same.

Comment: Is there a way to replace latin-basic with latin-1 supplimental?

Comment: @tree regex don't provide a way to remap characters based character classes. There is a way to replace individual groups which might be used for such a thing but that would get very complex and probably not be the best solution. Instead you might want to use a plain old loop and replace characters one-by-one. How should those be mapped anyway? Would `A` be mapped to `À`, `Á`, `Â` etc.?